# Can't detect USB camera when connected with 10m cable

Tags: webcam, streaming, video-recording

I have two Logitech cameras which are connected and working properly.

But when they are connected using two 10m cables they are not working.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB 1.1/2.0 states that maximum cable length is 5M or about 16' for transmission speeds. It depends on the quality of the cable, shielding, and other factors. I would personally use a cable that's no longer than 3m or about 10', to ensure that you get a high quality image out of your webcam.

Answer (score 1):

The USB standard offers both a really low voltage of 5V and a really low current range of 0.5-2.0A, so you are simply underpowering your device because with your long cable you are wasting power over the distance. There are limits to how long the cable can be depending also on the cable quality, but as a general rule of thumb you should keep things in the 1-1.5 meter range, or you could use some externally powered cable if available.